# ArangoDB update query never completes

Tags: database, arangodb

I'm trying out ArangoDB and having some trouble. I successfully imported ~1.3 million documents and I'm trying to rearrange the document data in the database, but the following query (run through Arango shell) just slows Arango a crawl until eventually the shell gives me an error: `[ArangoError 2001: Error reading from: 'tcp://127.0.0.1:8529' 'timeout during read']`

```
FOR d IN DocumentCollection
    UPDATE d WITH {'uid': d.property1.property2} IN DocumentCollection
```

Should this query work? Am I doing something wrong? Is there some way to speed it up?

Comment: The query itself looks ok (apart from the semicolon at the end, which will throw a parse error). If it does not complete within a reasonable time, I guess that the system is I/O bound, probably because it is running out of RAM and swapping. If you can configure your system so that the updates will fit in RAM, too, that might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is (still) working. 
You can use [the queries Module](https://docs.arangodb.com/ModuleQueries/) to observe the query in action.

You can make arangosh wait more patiently with the --server.request-timeout - option.

The performance problem here is, that the whole collection has to be loaded into memory for this operation - since it can't chunk that internally (yet). 
If you are able to splice that into a series of queries using `FILTER` and ranges, you'd probably be faster at your target.

Comment: Thanks, you're correct and it did eventually finish. It's a bit confusing that the shell give you a command prompt again after the timeout error. Now to figure out the best way to split up the query...

Comment: Looks like such update queries will be optimized automatically in 2.7: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/commit/a2f2932a9dc3a10589b626dfc1cb1d2fe184f7f3

Comment: After hours of trial-and-error I managed to compile devel on Windows. I created 100k random documents, then updated them in different ways with AQL. Compared to 2.6.4, it's up to 8x faster if you add a static attribute to every document, ~5x faster if the new attribute name is dynamically created and `RANDOM_TOKEN()`/`DATE_NOW()` assigned as content, and ~3x faster if the old value is used to calculate a new value. So generally a good speedup. It needs some more in-depth benchmarking however to see how well it performs under different conditions, like collection sizes and document complexity.

Comment: The update sounds great! Can't wait. I'm trying a different query now and it finally completed after 12 hours... but afterward Arango is still working on something and extremely slow: .current() returns nothing but disk usage is still quite high. Is there some other way to check what Arango is working on?

Comment: you can use `top -c <pid of arango>`  and press `M` to sort by used memory, and finally `H` to show threads.  They are named by their actual work scope - which may give additional insights.